# I got this error after deploying to heroku and thus it couldn't display

Tags: node.js

Error: Cannot find module './middleware/errorMiddleware'
Require stack:

- /app/backend/server.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (/app/backend/server.js:6:26)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/app/backend/server.js' ]

Process exited with status 1
State changed from starting to crashed
State changed from crashed to starting
Starting process with command `npm start`

> mern-shopping-list@1.0.0 start
> node backend/server.js
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
> throw err;

Answer (score 0):

**try this command**
npm install -g npm@latest

npm i core-util-is

or
npm i core-util-is

or
remove node then install nodejs LTS from nodejs.org